# How do I get data from dynamically generated text fields in Java?

Tags: java, dynamic, arraylist, runtime, textfield

I have generated N text fields using for loop (N is the number of inputs entered by user). I want to get data entered by user in those text fields and save it in an ArrayList. I don't know the name of those fields so is there any way to get the text fields names? Or how do I store data from N textfields to an `ArrayList` and use values from that ArrayList. Here is my code:

```
public class FCFS extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton btn1,btn2,b;
    JTextField tf1,tf2;
    JPanel p;
    Container c;
    ArrayList arr=new ArrayList();
    public FCFS(){
        //super("FCFS");
        c=getContentPane();
        p=new JPanel();
        JLabel lbl1=new JLabel("Enter number of processes:");
        p.add(lbl1);
        tf1=new JTextField(20);
        p.add(tf1);
        btn1=new JButton("Enter");
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        p.add(btn1);
        c.add(p);

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        FCFS obj=new FCFS();
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.setSize(300,500);
        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getSource()==btn1){
            p.removeAll();
            int a=Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
            for(int i=1;i<=a;i++){
                p.add(new JLabel("Enter Burst for Process "+i+":"));
                tf2=new JTextField(20);
                p.add(tf2);
                arr.add(tf2.getText());
                c.add(p);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
            b=new JButton("Show");
            p.add(b);
            c.add(p);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
            b.addActionListener(this);
        }
        else if(ae. getSource()==b){
            System.out.println("Hello");
            System.out.println(arr);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the *name* of the fields, you need the fields themselves. You can iterate over the `Panel`, and find all the text fields, or you can keep them in the array, and then extract their values when you want to use it:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    if(ae.getSource()==btn1){
        p.removeAll();
        int a=Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
        for(int i=1;i<=a;i++){
            p.add(new JLabel("Enter Burst for Process "+i+":"));
            tf2=new JTextField(20);
            p.add(tf2);
            arr.add(tf2);
        }
        b=new JButton("Show");
        p.add(b);
        c.add(p);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        b.addActionListener(this);
    }
    else if(ae.getSource()==b){
        System.out.println("Hello");
        ArrayList texts=new ArrayList();
        for (Object textField : arr) {
            texts.add(((JTextField)textField).getText();
        }
        System.out.println(texts);
    }
}
```

Comment: i've done changes in code according to your suggestion.. but now it is giving error:
 "Incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to JTextField"
on this line:
  for (JTextField textField : arr) {

Comment: thanks .. but now it is giving an error:  "cannot find symbol  ..symbol: method getText()  ..Location: variable jTextField of type object" on line:  `texts.add((JTextField) textField.getText());`

Comment: thank you .. it worked  i've also tried :    `List<JTextField> list = new ArrayList<JTextField>();`
`for(JTextField field : list){`
             ` arr.add( field.getText());`
            `} `
and it worked

Comment: ..now am trying to use integer values saved in ArrayList ... i want to get value from ArrayList and fill them in JTable after some calculations ... like `int n =arr.get(1);` but it gives an error : "Object cannot be converted into int" .. can u please help me to solve this problem .. thanks

Comment: I can only guess you are trying to cast the text values into integers. You will need to parse them - 'int n = Integer.parse(texts.get(0))'

Comment: ..parsing didn't work ... i've tried another thing that worked ... i've changed ArrayList type to integer like this: `ArrayList<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<Integer>();` ... and now i can directely get and save values from any index to int variable `int n=arr.get(3);`

Comment: now i need another favor ... what i'm trying to do is, find the smallest integer in that ArrayList(i.e. arr) and store its index in another Array/ArrayList at a[0].. then find the second smallest integer an save its index in the same Array/ArrayList at a[1] and so on until we get and save index of every integer saved in ArrayList (i.e. arr) ... and thanks for the help (-:

Comment: @MuhammadShuja - what you need is to sort the array - I suggest you search this site (or others) to find many answers on this question